# Firefox and onscroll failing from greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, dom, greasemonkey

I've noticed that a greasemonkey script I wrote a while back is no longer working, maybe due to me using Firefox 4 now (although I don't have an earlier version of Firefox on hand with which I could verify this theory).

It does the following:

```
myelm.addEventListener('scroll', fonscroll, false);
```

This used to work, but now it seems to fail silently. Moreover, if I try the following instead:

```
myelm.onscroll = fonscroll;
```

I get the following error:

```
[Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: jar:file:///~/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/wo832x2w.default/extensions/%7Be4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781%7D.xpi!/components/greasemonkey.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. It turns out that Firefox no longer likes to let me use CSS to scroll a `tbody` independently of its `thead`. My unhappy compromise was to just periodically repeat the `thead` - even though this is malformed HTML, it renders.

Answer (score 0):

what is the element type of `myelm`? I tried to add a scroll event listener to an iframe

Comment: I might be missing something here, but can't only frames and windows be scrolled?

Comment: Originally this worked, and the tbody could be scrolled. Apparently Firefox has pulled support for this feature. I'll post an answer when I have some working code.